# Lambda connect to Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have lambda function like below

```
// Loads in the AWS SDK
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

// Creates the document client specifing the region 
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'}); 
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // Handle promise fulfilled/rejected states
    await readMessage().then(data => {
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item.message)
        });
        callback(null, {
            // If success return 200, and items
            statusCode: 200,
            body: data.Items,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        // If an error occurs write to the console
        console.error(err);
    })
};

// Function readMessage
// Reads 10 messages from the DynamoDb table Message
// Returns promise
function readMessage() {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Message',
        Limit: 10
    }
    return ddb.scan(params).promise();
}
```

my dynamo db is in region us-east-1 , but above code is not running , it is just timing out.But i am able to run simple hello world inside handler function  , and it just works fine.

I have enabled VPC with 6 subnets.. also disabled VPC , not matter what it is timing out without any error logs.. I even increased timeout to 5 mins , it did not do anything.Should I install aws-sdk or something ? Sorry I am completely new to lambda.

Comment: 1. Do your lambda have IAM permissions to access this table?
  
2. when the lambda is async, don't use the callback but return the value directly as an object.

Comment: aws-sdk is already present in lambda environment.

Comment: yes I have IAM role with Allow: dynamodb:*

Comment: Try to change the callback by a return

Comment: ok It seems like we need to create in endpoint in VPC to dynamodb , once I did that , it is working smooth.. code is correct